# how to i send bcc or cc email in my mail function but i have tried code but bcc or cc function is not working?

Tags: php, email, sendmail

how to i send bcc or cc email in my mail function but i have tried code but bcc or cc function is not working?

```
<?php
//SENDS EMAIL THAT TELLS THE USER TO ACTIVATE THE ACCOUNT
$activation = 'activation.php?key='.$key;
$your_email = 'non-reply@mydomain.pk'; //CHANGE TO YOUR SETTINGS
$domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; //YOUR DOMAIN AND EXTENSION
$to  = $email;
$subject = 'MyDomain Activate Account';
$message .='<img src="http://mydomain.com/images/securedownload.jpg"/>';
$message = 'Welcome,<br/> '.$_POST['username'].'. You must activate your account via   this       message to log in. Click the following link to do so:   http://'.$domain.'/'.$activation;
$headers .= "BCC: MyDomain Order Copy <demo@mydomain.com>\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= "From: MyDomain <'.$your_email.'@'.$domain.'>\r\n" .  
//"Reply-To: $from \r\n" .  
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();    
?>
```

Comment: It is a good idea asking same question every 20 minutes

Comment: I can't see a `mail()` call in your code - is there more of it? In any case, a library is recommended to send email - try SwiftMailer or one of several others.

Comment: Thanks @Mahmut, voting to close. OP, please don't ask questions more than once.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark yes it is because of i think there is problem of question ?

Comment: @halfer sorry for that